# Masking and cut transparent image

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap, mask

I have two images one over other. Uppper image is having some transparent portion, I want to cut that portion and place it in sd card.
Also the below image can be zoomed in/out/scaled.

Can any one help me in this ?[image]

I appreciate if anyone even can provide me some idea.

[image]

Comment: Are you going to show us the images?

Comment: how can I upload that image here???

Comment: Put a link to it someplace where it is stored as a PNG which supports transparency.

Comment: Edit your question, press `Ctrl+G`. You'll see the option to upload image.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Bitmap object to draw to that is the same size as the Upper image.
Create a Canvas object and pass this bitmap to its constructor so that you are drawing into the bitmap.

Draw the Lower image on the canvas with a transformation Matrix that represents your zoom/pan etc.

Then iterate over the pixels in the upper bitmap and the one you just drew into and set the alpha value of the pixels in the new bitmap to that in the upper image.  Maybe there is another way of applying an alpha mask but I did not see one after a quick skim of the Canvas class interface - maybe looking a bit closer would reveal something.

Alternatively for better performance, use OpenGL and write a shader to do it using your two images.  You can render to texture and pull the data back from the render texture.  More complicated to do than the other method.